# Fetch Google Contacts API version 3.0 Android

Tags: android, google-contacts-api

I am fetching google contacts in my app.

As i took the reference from following links:

https://tush.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/android-google-contact-api-3-0-example/

[How to get gmail user's contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125500/how-to-get-gmail-users-contacts)

But now Google is adding security so when i am trying to fetch contacts its showing me warning that "Authorization requests in embedded browsers will be blocked soon".

if i am adding the code which provided in the google docs i.e. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts then i am getting error that "No authorization header added".

Comment: did u enable Contacts API in ur dev console ?

Comment: You have to authorise ur request -> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_to_the_api_name_service

Comment: @AkshayMahajan, Yes i have enabled the api

Comment: I am not able to get how to authorise the app https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_to_the_api_name_service

Comment: Just follow the steps on how to Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0

Comment: Have you created OAuth 2.0 client ID from your dev console ? This will authorise your app to retrieve user's data.

Comment: Yes, i have created the same

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same kind of problem, maybe this link can help you understanding your authentification issue https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab/index.html

Comment: Yes , i already found the same link. Thanks for your concern. @estoke

Comment: Have you gone through the official Google documentation about how to fetch Google contacts?

Comment: Hi @MamtaKaundal have you found solution?